# Set theory problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to prove this statement:

$(\bigcup\textbf{S})\times(\bigcup\textbf{T})\subseteq\bigcup\{\textbf{X}\times\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}\in\textbf{S},\textbf{Y}\in\textbf{T}\}$ for all sets $\textbf{S},\textbf{T}$ of sets. Also, i would like to prove that we cannot replace $ ``\subseteq "$ by $``="$.

Any suggestions or full solution? Thanks in advance!

R.T.

EDIT: Although the inclusion is straightforward (thx to Brian), it's still not clear to me the last ‘‘⇐". Thx again!

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion is straightforward, and we **can** always replace it with equality:

$$\langle s,t\rangle\in\left(\bigcup\mathbf{S}\right)\times\left(\bigcup\mathbf{T}\right)$$

if and only if

$$\text{there are }\mathbf{X}\in\mathbf{S}\text{ and }\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbf{T}\text{ such that }s\in\mathbf{X}\text{ and }t\in\mathbf{Y}$$

if and only if

$$\text{there are }\mathbf{X}\in\mathbf{S}\text{ and }\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbf{T}\text{ such that }\langle s,t\rangle\in\mathbf{X}\times\mathbf{Y}$$

if and only if

$$\langle s,t\rangle\in\bigcup\{\mathbf{X}\times\mathbf{Y}:\mathbf{X}\in\mathbf{S}\text{ and }\mathbf{Y}\in\mathbf{T}\}\;.$$

Comment: Yes we **can**!